# Dynamic mapping an entity to multiple tables

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I just searched for dynamic mapping with eclipselink, I cannot find a solution for my case, now in my system, an entity have 3 versions, one is working/draft (i.e. W100), another is  is production (i.e. M100), and remaining one is history version (H100), at any time, we may access both working,production and history versions.
i.e.

```
Account account = // query from working.
account.setStatus("APPROVED");
account.increaseVersionNo();
myJPAEngine.updateApproved(account); // this step update status to both working and production
//, and W100.PRODUCTION_IPKEY = M100.IPKEY 
// (if production version does't exist
//, create a new one with same columns as working version).
//, if increaseVersionNo() called, then we need copy old 'M'- production record to 'H' history version table.
//, my JPA engine need access both 'W'/'M'/'H' tables at same time by passing a parameter to JPA API metadata classes by ThreadLocal or other related workaround.
```

Does eclipselink (or Hibernate) support this? my dynamic mapping accept a parameter to decide which table is used, that is to say this is an interactive dynamic mapping.
  Can and how we plugin some customization into eclipselink metadata classes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Table name is mapped into an entity class using xml configuration / annotation, so I doubt you can change it at runtime

The only way I can think of is by using entity manager native query, eg:

```
String sql = "select xyz from " + tableName;
List<MyEntity> reuslt = em.createNativeQuery(sql, MyEntity.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: 'Update' operation can use 'native update' like feature?
I want to plugin my customization to JPA metadata API classes, but I'm not sure this.

Comment: Yes you can use variant that does not take class parameter: `createNativeQuery(java.lang.String sqlString)`

Answer (score 0):

I would create three subclasses of Account (DraftAccount, ActiveAccount, HistoricalAccount) and use a @MappedSuperclass or TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance.  To switch the account you would delete the old account and create a new one.

Another alternative is to to define a VIEW to make the three tables look like one (or actually change to have one table with a TYPE column).

You can customize EclipseLink operations using custom SQL, stored procedure or query redirectors, but I would recommend changing your model over faking it underneath.